# Majorana Fermions in superconductors (Wikipedia page)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-phase, majorana-fermions

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion#Majorana_bound_states), Majorana Fermions in supercondutors are described as

> Mathematically, the superconductor imposes electron hole "symmetry" on the quasiparticle excitations, relating the creation operator $\gamma^\dagger (E)$ at energy $E$ to the annihilation operator $\gamma(-E)$ at energy $-E$. Majorana fermions can be bound to a defect at zero energy, and then the combined objects are called Majorana bound states or Majorana zero modes.

The reference which was given doesn't seem to explain this, and I'm confused to what is meant here. Is it the case that a Majorana Fermion creation operator is defined by combining these two Fermionic operators, something along the lines of $f = \gamma(E) + \gamma(-E)^\dagger$. This is not a Majorana Fermion, it squared is 0, and it's not real, meaning $f \neq f ^\dagger$. Is it only at zero energy that it is a Majorana? And at the other energies, is it still a creation operator for something?